# Interaction with pm2 process using http

Tags: node.js, pm2

I gone through pm2 documentation, There is a keymetric application by pm2. 
It uses link parameter, and based on public and private key, it monitor status of application.

My question is, Can I configure pm2 to send spastics to my own server instead of pm2 server?
I found web api of pm2 but it requires ajax calls from web server. Instead of this is there any way that, application itself send statistics and heartbeat to specified URL?

Answer (score 0):

Nope it's not possible, you can go though the BUS and RPC system of PM2 to do this